# What will be the SQL Error code for Oracle database while org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection exception is thrown?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, c3p0, oracle-rac

We are using hibernate's c3p0 connection provider in order to interact with the DB from our application.
In case of Oracle RAC failover scenario, whenever the transaction is established and failover happens the DB throws this exception: `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection`

I would like to know the SQL error code for this exception and based on that we would like to implement the retry logic in our application.

Answer (score 0):

If a RAC failover happens in the middle of a transaction (i.e. no commit has happened) then the transaction is automatically rolled back by the database. The application must reconnect or switch to a pooled connection from a working instance (the original session to the failed instance will not be usable) and replay the transaction.

As there are a variety of reasons for a RAC failover event, not all of which are even visible within the database, there isn't any one specific SQL code to watch for. Oracle Grid Infrastructure can generate messages using Fast Application Notification or Fast Connection Failover paradigms to applications so that they can reconnect as necessary.

See the documentation on application continuity for more: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/racad/ensuring-application-continuity.html

Comment: We are using Datadirect's oracle driver so the features provided by oracle OCI driver implementation will not be applicable in my application. So when the failover happens I need to rely upon the exception thrown from the database end and my application should be smart enough to understand the RAC failover from the exception code. I have collected a few such SQL codes 08006, HY000, HY008, and 08001, and looking for which are still left.

Comment: Those appear to be DataDirect codes, not Oracle codes. As I stated there are a number of events that could cause a failover that would only be visible from the infrastructure level and would be transparent to the database itself - i.e. that wouldn't throw an Oracle-generated code at all. Trying to build a comprehensive list of codes is likely pointless. Validate every connection in your pool before attempting to use it, and react to any broken connection (*any* exception, regardless of cause) the same way: re-establish and repeat the current transaction.